# Initial zeros stripped of when using Max in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, max, sqlfiddle

To test -

```
CREATE TABLE shop (
    article INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL DEFAULT '0000' NOT NULL,
    dealer  CHAR(20)                 DEFAULT ''     NOT NULL,
    price   DOUBLE(16,2)             DEFAULT '0.00' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(article, dealer));
INSERT INTO shop VALUES
    (1,'A',3.45),(1,'B',3.99),(2,'A',10.99),(3,'B',1.45),
    (3,'C',1.69),(3,'D',1.25),(4,'D',19.95);
```

My Query -

```
SELECT MAX( article ) AS article
FROM shop
```

It outputs -

```
+---------+
| article |
+---------+
|       4 |
+---------+
```

However I was expecting -

```
+---------+
| article |
+---------+
|    0004 |
+---------+
```

I tried to `CAST` but no luck.

Let me know how could I handle this.

FYI- I tried to create SQL Fiddle for this but fiddle is not filling Zeros http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4abbe/24 when executed `SELECT * FROM shop`

However in `phpmyadmin` its working correctly with `ooo's` fill.

`MySQL` setting - Server version: 5.5.16
`PHPMYADMIN` setting - Version information: 3.4.5

My table data representation -

[image: table data]

Comment: If leading 0s are significant for your data, it doesn't sound like `INT` is the right data type to use.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever then should i store it in VARCHAR or any other for leading zeros? your suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  LPAD(MAX( article ), 4, '0') AS article FROM shop;
```

;-)

Comment: Hey, mate. I know that you mean. =/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`LPAD()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad).

```
SELECT LPAD(article, 4, 0) FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using ZEROFILL it is actually storing it in database in that form but while retrieving it truncates the zero. So you should use:-

```
SELECT  LPAD(MAX( article ), 4, '0') AS article FROM shop;
```